# Cat activates mystery prompt

Tags: arch-linux, prompt

My cat stepped on the keyboard today and the resulting garbage caused a ">" prompt to appear. The text was something like "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~YYYY~~~~~~~~~~~       ]]]]]]]]". I could not get the prompt to answer me. I tried things like "?, help, ls, q" etc and it would just make no answer and the prompt would come back. Is there anyway I can figure out what the prompt is?

Comment: you could have confused everyone and said that the `cat` command is producing weird results ...... lol

Comment: Also a dupe of [In which situations are PS2, PS3, PS4 used as the prompt?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/193659) which contains better explanations.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused when something is entered into the terminal that looks like an expression that requires more input from the user or is a unclosed quotation that causes the terminal to also expect more input.

For Example if you type: `echo "Hello` then press enter, you get the carrot.

Then if you type `"` and press enter it will complete as expected. If you type anything else it behaves as you have seen until you `"` and then it will spit out what ever it was, or you will have to ^C.